# UITextView contentsize.height issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, contentsize

I searched & spend so much time to resolve the issue of content size height, but it’s hard luck, nothing worked. Similar questions are available in stack & other forums also but i am not getting what is left, which is not allowing my textview to resolve this issue.

I have to place textView’s cursor & text at centre of it’s width & height. Now i use it-

```
        UITextView *tv = object;

        [tv setScrollEnabled:YES];
        CGFloat height = [tv bounds].size.height;
        CGFloat contentheight;

       contentheight = [tv sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tv.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height;
         NSLog(@"iOS7; %f %f", height, contentheight);
//        [tv sizeToFit];
        CGFloat topCorrect = height - contentheight;
        topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
        tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
         [tv setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

The Second Approach i used is-

```
#pragma mark- UITextView ContentHeight Messurment

- (CGFloat)measureHeightOfUITextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    {
        // This is the code for iOS 7. contentSize no longer returns the correct value, so
        // we have to calculate it.
        //
        // This is partly borrowed from HPGrowingTextView, but I've replaced the
        // magic fudge factors with the calculated values (having worked out where
        // they came from)

        CGRect frame = textView.bounds;

        // Take account of the padding added around the text.

        UIEdgeInsets textContainerInsets = textView.textContainerInset;
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = textView.contentInset;

        CGFloat leftRightPadding = textContainerInsets.left + textContainerInsets.right + textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding * 2 + contentInsets.left + contentInsets.right;
        CGFloat topBottomPadding = textContainerInsets.top + textContainerInsets.bottom + contentInsets.top + contentInsets.bottom;

        frame.size.width -= leftRightPadding;
        frame.size.height -= topBottomPadding;

        NSString *textToMeasure = textView.text;
        if ([textToMeasure hasSuffix:@"\n"])
        {
            textToMeasure = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-", textView.text];
        }

        // NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
        // available only on ios7.0 sdk.

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: textView.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };

        CGRect size = [textToMeasure boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame), MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:attributes
                                                  context:nil];

        CGFloat measuredHeight = ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(size) + topBottomPadding);
        return measuredHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        return textView.contentSize.height;
    }
}
```

The response is coming like it- 
[image]
After editing it, it's appearing like it- 
[image]

Now, what else i can try to put textView's text on the centre of UITextView? Please update me.

Comment: Did you try to use `NSTextAlignmentCenter`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it too..didn't work...Thanks for quick & nice response.

Comment: Can you please provide a snapshot of what you want?

Comment: @Morpheus: Please see i update my questions with screenshot of issue.

Comment: @iPatel: Yes, I need to enter text at centre & show text at centre of UITextView.

Comment: May be it's an issue of vertical alignment. Try to use `txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;`

Comment: @Nico - you can check my answer :)

Comment: @Morpheus: Please see...It's UITextView, not textField.